# installation de CiviCrm

Tags: wordpress

"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$this' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-14.1VC9\data\localweb\wordpress\wp-content\plugins\civicrm\civicrm\CRM\Core\DAO.php on line 1124"

Résultat de (installation copier dossier civicrm dans répertoire plugins.)

ou

" le lien est expiré" résultat de (installation à partir de téléverser une extension, fichier zip.)

j'y comprends rien.

merci

Answer (score 1):

Philippe, Welcome to CiviCRM SE.

It looks like your server is using older version of php. Can you please check [here](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#php-version) if your server is using any one of the ones that are incompatible? If so you will need to upgrade your php.

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Merci et bonne journée